# How can I store an existing html element and create it later?

Tags: javascript, html, createelement

I have a very simple html code here. I want to store the whole div test_area and then create it when I need it. For now, let's assume that I want to duplicate it and put the clone below the existing element, how can I do that? Here's what I tried to do which didn't work (specifically the innerHtml line):

```html
<body>
    <div class="test_area" id="test_area">
        <h1>
            This is a test
        </h1>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    let current_element = document.getElementById('test_area')
    let clone = document.createElement('div')
    clone.innerHTML = current_element
    document.body.appendChild(clone)
</script>
```

In the end I want the final html version to look like this:

## This is a test

## This is a test

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you want to do with the element. You can store it in a variable and then render somewhere or you could store it to localstore or send to server or what ever you like. Here is a simple example:

```
<div class="test_area" id="test_area">
    <h1>
        This is a test
    </h1>
</div>

<div id="clonearea"></div>

 const current_element = document.getElementById('test_area');
 const clonearea = document.getElementById('clonearea');
 const clone = current_element.cloneNode(true);
 clonearea.appendChild(clone);
```

You can read more about cloning here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

And here is a codepen example: https://codepen.io/shnigi/pen/LYRQGOW

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert the old object in a JSON, and then parsing it and save it to a var.

```
let myObject = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( myOldObject ) );
```

this way you can access myObject and display it whenever you want.

---

Take a look to this question : 
[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This is not cloning, but a way to create and append in one line:

```js
document.getElementById("test_area").appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement("h1"), {textContent: "This is a test"}))
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="test_area" id="test_area">
        <h1>
            This is a test
        </h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

To actually clone, use `cloneNode`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

```js
let p = document.getElementById("test_area").children[0]
let p_prime = p.cloneNode(true)

document.getElementById("test_area").appendChild(p_prime)
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="test_area" id="test_area">
        <h1>
            This is a test
        </h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the only thing i should have done to fix this problem is use the variable's innerHTML and append it on the body, like this. I had totally forgotten that current element is an object, not the html code itself.

```js
const current_element = document.getElementById('test_area');
document.body.appendChild(current_element.innerHTML)
```